# How tomake input optional, or how ot check is there any tokens on input stream

Tags: java, inputstream

So I would like to have option when i input list, if i don't put any path i want program to use current directory it is in but it is just waiting for me to input something.
what do i have to do if i do not input anything for program to continue.
**What method should I use instead of Scanner.hasNext() o check if there is any tokens on input stream .**

```java
String function = scanner.next();
switch (function) {
    case "list":
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        path = scanner.next();
        list(path, 0);
    } else {
        list(System.getProperty("user.dir"), 0);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do exactly what you're trying, but there are options.

**Option 1 - have different commands**

`list` vs `list_default`, for example, although `list_default` is not the prettiest

**Option 2: two separate prompts**

```
> Enter a command
list
> Enter directory to search (defaults to user directory)
```

After the second prompt, if the user just hit `Enter`, you'd go with user dir, but if he entered a directory path, you'd use that

**Option 3: more complicated command**

`list` would list user directory, while `list /some/path` would list `some/path`.

Comment: so task is if i input only list it should use curent directory I am in and if he enters list "path" it lists in that directory. 

option 1-is not option because task is to be one command.
 
option 2 i am not sure would this work default  for current directory is good idea but i cant give all options because  i can have million possible paths.

option 3 I do not get what are you saying

Comment: Option 3: the command is either just `list` or `list /path/to/directory`.  In the first case, you'd use the default directory, in the second, whatever the user entered after `list`

Comment: i wrote that in code but how do i do it, because i do not think it is posible with scanner.hasNext(). Is there a method or function that makes input optional if there is nothing. what would you use becouse scanner.hasNext() doesnt work.

Comment: how do i implement third option i tryed doing it with .hasNext() but it doesn't work do you know what can i implement

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *scanner.nextLine()* instead of *scanner.next()* ?

Comment: yes it is same problem. I researched a bit and it looks like scanner.hasNext() works only in files it doesn't work with classic input stream.So if you have a solution to this problem pleas post :)